# Does the converse of the following theorem hold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

If $f (x)  \leq g(x)$ for  all $x \in [a, b]$, then   $$   \int_a^b f (x) \,dx \leq \int_a^b g(x)\, dx.$$

Any suggestions and solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the inverse is clearly false.

Comment: You can find some simple counterexamples to the converse by thinking of the integral as the area under the curve. Try to find a counterexample with a triangle and a rectangle, for instance.

Comment: "The winner of a race is alwayss driving faster than the loser".

Comment: Just $∫(g(x)-f(x))dx$.

Comment: Do you mean the inverse of the statement or the converse if the statement? Because the inverse is essentially the same thing

Answer (score 2):

The converse statement is false in general. For example, let $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = \dfrac{3}{4}$. Then

$$\int\limits_0^1 f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} < g(x)$$ but $f(1) > g(1)$.

Geometrically this means that the area under $f(x)$ is less than the area under $g(x)$ in $[0, 1]$, but there obviously exists a point, where $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$ in this interval.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the converse, then it is false:

Take $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$ and the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Then $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin x \, dx=1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos x \, dx$$

But $\sin \frac \pi 2 =1 \gt \cos \frac \pi 2 =0$